# Which Animorphs books have description of the Yeerk Pool?

Tags: setting, k-a-applegate, animorphs

I want to refer to descriptions of the Yeerk Pool from K. A. Applegate's *Animorphs* series. This is for a short story I'm working on which would be set within the main Pool complex. However, there are a *lot* of books, and I'm not sure which would be relevant. Which books have description of the **inside of the Yeerk Pool** complex?

This **includes**:

- Any *Animorphs* book canon, both the main series and associated supplementals such as *Chronicles*
- Scenes set within the Pool complex
- Secondhand description of the Pool complex, *if providing new information* (i.e. not simple repetition of the primary-source scenes within the Pool complex)
- Memories of/flashbacks to the Pool complex, *if providing new information*
- Description within a scene of what happens in the Pool complex, even if the characters are outside (e.g. if they are trying to break in and hear an alarm go off inside)

This **does not include**:

- Any non-book media, including the television series, video games, etc.
- Speculation about what *could* be in the Pool complex (e.g. during planning scenes)
- Description of an entrance to the Pool complex if focused solely on the entrance and its security (but again, if something happens *inside* the Pool complex while the characters are outside of an entrance, such as an alarm, then that description still counts)

Ideally an answer would give a list of book titles, their numbers within the series, and page numbers for the relevant scenes. I would however settle for just titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's included in this answer

I omitted dream sequences since it’s not clear what in those is real and what is all a dream. I figured that anything in dreams which was true would be based on an earlier scene of actually being at the Pool. I also omitted vague, repetitive descriptions such as

> “As the rest of you know, the Yeerk pool is in a huge underground cavern. It’s practically a small city down there. It’s under our school, but it’s so big that it also runs beneath the fire station, a couple of gas stations, and most of the mall.”
> <sub>Chapter 4 of #7 (*The Stranger*)</sub>

These appear in very similar iterations in multiple books. They are typically summaries of previous exposition, and include some combination of: the Pool is under the town, it is large, it has entrances in various places, and it features a sludge-like pool full of Yeerks, cages for involuntary hosts, screams, etc. Thus they aren’t useful if you were only trying to study the Pool complex as a setting: being summary, they don’t offer new information.

I give book numbers in addition to titles. Numbers without a qualifier are from the main series, while numbers with a qualifier are from companion series. Books are in chronological order.

### The List!

- #1 (*The Invasion*): End of Ch. 17, Ch. 22-26
- #7 (*The Stranger*): Ch. 10-12, Ch. 14-15
- #17 (*The Underground*): Ch. 20-29
- #29 (*The Sickness*): Ch. 20-24
- #33 (*The Illusion*): Ch. 25-26
- Chronicles #3 (*Visser*): Ch. 22-23, Ch. 27
- #37 (*The Weakness*): Ch. 19-21
- #38 (*The Arrival*): Ch. 25-27
- #43 (*The Test*): Ch. 20
- #45 (*The Revelation*): Ch. 16-21
- #52 (*The Sacrifice*): Ch. 27-28

### Extra notes (contains spoilers)

- #1 (*The Invasion*) has description in Chapter 12 of what a Yeerk pool is. However, it is only about the concept and biological requirement of a Pool, not anything specific to the one under the town.
- #7 (*The Stranger*) technically spends Chapter 13 in the Pool complex, but the Ellimist is giving everyone trippy visions the whole time so I didn’t count it. Later, in Chapters 19-21, there is description of a future Pool, which I did not count as it’s not the one in question.
- Megamorphs #1 (*The Andalite's Gift*) contains various snippets from the Pool, but since the character in question has amnesia, the scenes are disjointed and confused. Thus, I ruled out including them in the list.
- Both [Altermorphs](https://animorphs.fandom.com/wiki/Alternamorphs) books have references to, and scenes in, the Pool complex, however, they are non-canonical and are thus not included in the list.
- #33 (*The Illusion*) technically is located somewhere in the Pool much earlier, around Chapter 13 is where I would put it. However, the characters are in an interrogation room. They’re separated from the main area until the floor gets a hole in it for stuff to fall through.
- Chronicles #3 (*Visser*) technically takes place entirely within the Pool complex. However, quite a lot of it is flashbacks to a time before the Pool existed. The rest is largely stuck within a single trial room separated from the main area. There are two chapters (28 and 29) where the characters are located outside of the trial room, but there is literally no description of the surroundings. Thus, they were not included in the main list.
- Megamorphs #4 (*Back to Before*) has scenes in the Pool but, as it takes place in an alternate timeline, is not canon enough for this purpose.

Method: I acquired e-books and search them for the word “Pool”.